# How does a wireless USB mouse or keyboard work?

Tags: usb, wireless, hid

Wireless mouse or keyboard works on the principle of radio frequency (RF) technology.

The transmitter of a wireless device is located inside the device itself and it sends the electromagnetic signals to the receiver which is located in the USB.

Then what happens? Does the USB adapter work as a receiver and then act as a wired USB HID device or it does interact with the system directly?

Comment: FWIW both device and USB dongle have bidirectional transceivers.  It's not correct to talk about one transmitter and one receiver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The USB adapter presents standard HID keyboard and/or mouse devices to the PC just like a wired keyboard or mouse does.

Comment: It might.  It might also present a bus to the PC, and rely on driver software of the PC to enumerate attached devices and present RF bus-attached HID devices rather than USB-attached HID devices.  You'll almost certainly see this more complex scenario when the wireless protocol is Bluetooth.

Comment: @BenVoigt Quite right, if it is a Bluetooth dongle, the it will show as a Bluetooth interface and then standard Bluetooth mice and keyboards will show as Bluetooth devices. But it will work only when an OS that supports Bluetooth is started, it won't work in BIOS like standard USB dongles, so anything sold will typically be sold with a USB HID receiver or without a dongle if it is Bluetooth.

Comment: Often true, but for example the F8T041-B was a bundle of Bluetooth mouse and USB dongle (described as a Bluetooth adapter supporting up to 7 devices, so it wasn't some cut down direct-to-HID dongle).  Non-bluetooth examples of exposing a bus rather than direct HID emulation would include W-USB (although too expensive for use in mice and keyboards), and [Zigbee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_interface_device#Other_protocols_using_HID)